# Solving for coefficients of a polynomial?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, polynomials

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm damned if I can figure out what. I'm trying to find a cubic function that passes through (0, 270), (1, 312), (2,230), (3,0), but the first way I tried it did not work:

In:

```
f[x_] := a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d;
Solve[f[0] == 270 && f[1] == 312 && f[2] == 230 && f[3] == 0, {a, b, c, d}]
```

Out:

```
{{b -> -62 - 3 a, c -> 104 + 2 a, d -> 270}}
```

---

But this other method that I looked up *did* find the right answer:

In:

```
Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 270}, {1, 312}, {2, 230}, {3, 0}}, x]]
```

Out:

```
270 + 96 x - 50 x^2 - 4 x^3
```

---

Why does one work but not the other?

---

Update: I'm guessing I probably defined a value of the equation by accident (by typing f[1]=312 instead of f[1]==312, or similar) when I was mucking around trying to get the syntax right at the beginning, because upon restarting Mathematica, suddenly it works perfectly. So, all sorted!

Comment: What version are you using? When I enter your first two lines, I get the output `{a -> -4, b -> -50, c -> 96, d -> 270}}` Also, maybe try clearing out old definitions using `ClearAll["Global\`*"]`

Comment: I can confirm what @JasonB was saying. Using `$Version 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)`.

Comment: ...huh, I restarted Mathematica to try it again and check the version number (10.2), and pasted the line and retried, and this time it worked perfectly.

Aaaactually I wonder if when I was first setting it up maybe I typed one of those commands in with a single = sign instead of the double == by mistake, or got something else wrong because I was mucking around figuring out the syntax.